# List of Figures for a Single Section in an Article

Tags: table-of-contents, article

I have a document whose class is `article`. For a specific section only, I need to include the list of figures used within that section. I have tried using `\listoffigures` within that section and it printed all the figures used in the whole article.

I tried to use `minitoc` package, but as my document class is `article`, I am getting the error:

```
Package minitoc Error: E0037

(minitoc)                The \dominilof command is incompatible 
(minitoc)                with the document class.
```

`etoc` package doesn't seem designed to print a local list of figures, only ToCs.

Is there another way to address my problem?

Comment: You need \dosectlof and \sectlof (page 40).

Answer (score 1):

Following @JohnKormylo's comment, and since I am new to `minitoc`, I had to do the following to get the desired results:

```
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\dosectlof \fakelistoffigures

\section{..}
:

\section{..}
:

\clearpage

\section{Where list of figures is wanted}

% Print the list of figures under this section only:
\sectlof
:
```

Without `\clearpage`, some pending figures from previous sections would still show up after the start of the section and subsequently get printed in the local lof.

By the way, as `minitoc` is not maintained that much any more after the decease of its main maintainer, the package's documentation is no more available on CTAN's [minitoc page](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc?lang=en). I however found it [elsewhere](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minitoc/minitoc.pdf) if you are interested.